# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Service Not running, Was working until 3 days ago

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS Nginx Elastic beanstalk that was healthy and functioning on AWS Linux Node 16 NPM 5.8.2.

Few Days ago it stopped working after a minor update to one of the JS functions with error :

```
Following services are not running: web.
```

I tried rolling back the code to when it was healthy, it didn't work.
re deployed the environment probably 30 times and still not working.

AWS support is taking its sweet time to answer and our main application API is down.

any suggestions on where I should look at ?

Comment: Can you try running it in your machine and doing a clean install of the nodejs dependencies? I am suspecting its related to dependency change

Comment: No dependencies have changed, even when i used the code from the week earlier that was working until then even on a new environment to avoid caching got the same error. on my machine it's working as usual